# Handle the question where OP decided to reinstall the system and begin from scratch

Tags: discussion

Recently I going through unanswered questions pool to find *interesting* unsolved questions. In one question

[E-mails being relayed to other server](https://serverfault.com/questions/495763/e-mails-being-relayed-to-other-server)

there are no answer provided. Why? Because OP has solve his problem by [burn broken system and set them up from scratch](https://serverfault.com/questions/495763/e-mails-being-relayed-to-other-server#comment-556128).

Another example is this question [dovecot mysql auth mechanism](https://serverfault.com/questions/488222/dovecot-mysql-auth-mechanism). It was deleted  after I flagged it **Too localized, OP solved it by reinstall the system**.

Yes, those questions were on-topic. But, in the end OP decide to reinstall his system - [that may be useful to some future reader but it's not a useful sysadmin answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6535/218590). IMHO, reinstalling system was the last solution for every troubleshooting step.

What's the proper way to handle the question?  Should I flagged it for deletion like before?

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6159

Comment: Ah...Yes. Looks like this question was subset of question with no-possible-answer. And we should treat this type of question was same as above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper course of action is to get it deleted.  Flagging for deletion is one way to do that, on older posts with no answers, downvoting to -1 or lower will get it deleted when the cleanup scripts run each night.

[An older post on the auto-deletion criteria can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/196495).  I think the criteria may have changed slightly, but for your purposes, if you come across an old question like that with a 0 score, downvoting is a way to get it deleted without putting the work on the mods.

Comment: +1. Why should we putting work on mods when we can let the system do their jobs? It reminds me to featured meta discussion [How to find and clean up bad questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5781/how-to-find-and-clean-up-bad-questions)